# How to delete an element of a vector when the containing object contains an unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013, unique-ptr

I noticed that it isn’t possible to delete an element of a vector when the containing type contains an unique_ptr.

For example this class:

```
class Bar
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int> pointerTest;

        Bar(Bar &bar) {};

    public:
        Bar() { pointerTest = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int); }
        Bar(Bar &&bar) { this->pointerTest = move(bar.pointerTest); }

        void testFunc() { pointerTest.release(); }
    };
```

This doesn’t work with this usage:

```
int main()
    {
        vector<Bar> test123;

        Bar foo;
        test123.push_back(move(foo));
        test123.erase(test123.begin());
    }

    //Error 1   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 611 1   testing
```

The code will work when you only call the objects methods instead of the erase:

```
for (auto &item : test123)
    item.testFunc();
```

What is the reason why I can’t use erase on the vector and how could I solve this?

Comment: FWIW, your code compiles under g++ 4.6.

Comment: I can fix this on GCC 4.8 by removing the unnecessary move constructor and weird copy constructor. I don't know exactly what the problem is, or whether that will fix it for your compiler.

Comment: Strange, I can't compile this on visual studio 2013 with or without the copy and move constructor. @Mike Seymour What is wired about those constructors?

Comment: the error is clear, it attempt to call the assignment operator of `unique_ptr` that takes a const lvalue-reference, which is deleted from unique_ptr. your code never call it, maybe the problem is somewhere in your code which you don't show. perhap the destructor of Bar.

Comment: @yngum The code in this question is the full code I compile. You can find it here also: http://pastebin.com/jHNgSUi9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your class does not correctly follow the rule of three/five. You define a copy and move constructor, but not a move assignment operator. Which means no move assignment operator is generated and the default copy assignment operator is always used when assigning. However, since your class has a non-copyable member, the defaulted copy assignment operator is defined as deleted, so you get an error when using it.

And it's invoked because removing elements from a vector causes a shift (i.e. assignment) of all following elements of the vector. That would be a move assignment normally, but since that's not defined (and not auto-generated) in your class, copy assignment is invoked - and fails.

I see you're using Visual Studio, so a move constructor/move assignment operator wouldn't be auto-generated anyway (VS doesn't support this part of the standard yet). So to fix this in a VS-compatible way, define a move assignment operator. And it might be a good idea to remove the copy constructor while you're at it - the class looks like a prime example of a noncopyable class.

Answer (score 1):

The error message from g++ 4.8.1 is quite clear :

> garbage.cpp:9:11: note: ‘Bar& Bar::operator=(const Bar&)’ is
>   implicitly declared as deleted because ‘Bar’ declares a move
>   constructor or move assignment operator

By adding the move operator, the problem is solved :

```
class Bar
{
        std::unique_ptr<int> pointerTest;

        Bar(const Bar &);

public:
        Bar() { pointerTest = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int); }
        Bar(Bar &&bar) : pointerTest( move(bar.pointerTest)) {}
        Bar& operator=(Bar&& bar){ pointerTest = std::move(bar.pointerTest); return *this;}

        void testFunc() { pointerTest.release(); }
};
```